# Iterating POST data with PHP gives me stupid results

Tags: php, arrays, post

So I have this multi-dimensional $_POST array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [addonGroupName] => Testname
    [addons] => Array
        (
            [1534766970prkszomwvb] => Array
                (
                    ['title'] => Addon Title
                    ['products'] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    ['code'] => 1
                                    ['title'] => test product 
                                    ['price'] => 
                                    ['active'] => on
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Strangely I cant seem to access the value parts of the array, see what I mean:

```
    if(count($_POST['addons']) != 0)
    {
        foreach($_POST['addons'] as $key => $addon)
        {

            echo $key;
//prints 1534766970prkszomwvb



            print_r($addon);


            // prints
            Array
            (
                ['title'] => beta
                ['products'] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                ['code'] => 
                                ['title'] => 
                                ['deliveryPrice'] => 
                                ['pickupPrice'] => 
                                ['active'] => on
                            )

                    )

            )



            echo $addon['title'];
            // prints ""




        }
    }
```

Now I'm not new to programming but this has me pulling my hair out for a solid 2 hours now.

Is there something that I am missing or is there a limitation to the depth and accessibility of multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Where is `$addon` declared ?

Comment: Can you post the form?

Comment: Show us the code that sets `$addon` to something in the `$_POST` array. And a `print_r($_POST)`  would also be useful

Comment: what about the key 1534766970prkszomwvb and how did you get the $addons array?

Comment: Updated the code...

Comment: Try adding an `echo $key;` to see which key you are picking up. Its obviously not the one you think. And is that first array you posted the COMPLETE `$_POST` array

Comment: Try $addon[0]['title'] if it gets you the value.

Comment: echo $key just shows the key (1534766970prkszomwvb)

Comment: I just noticed you have two "title", which one is it you want to output? 'addon title' or 'test product'?

Comment: the addon['title']

Answer (score 0):

If this is the array:

```
Array
(
    [addonGroupName] => Testname
    [addons] => Array
        (
            [1534766970prkszomwvb] => Array
                (
                    ['title'] => Addon Title
                    ['products'] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    ['code'] => 1
                                    ['title'] => test product 
                                    ['price'] => 
                                    ['active'] => on
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

then the code you used:

```
foreach($_POST['addons'] as $key => $addon)
    {


        print_r($addon);
```

Should actually output:

```
            [1534766970prkszomwvb] => Array
                (
                    ['title'] => Addon Title
                    ['products'] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    ['code'] => 1
                                    ['title'] => test product 
                                    ['price'] => 
                                    ['active'] => on
                                )
                        )
                )
```

Which means there is another array in between: `1534766970prkszomwvb`

```
foreach($_POST['addons'] as $key => $addon){
        foreach($addon as $sub){
             print_r($sub);  // should give you the output in question.  
             echo $sub["title"]; // Addon Title
        }
}
```

---

If you want to output the products array you can use array_column to get the products array and loop that (if there is more than one item).

You can use array_column to get the "products" array.

```
$products = array_column($_POST, "products");
foreach($products as $prod){
    echo $prod["title"]; //test product
    echo $prod["code"]; //1
}
```

Comment: @Bogodan_SS1 And you are sure it's not `echo $sub["title"][0]`? that is a very big difference.

Comment: @Bogodan_SS1 As I see it there is no other reason why it would only output the first character. if you add [x] to a string it will output the x-th character of the string